# Problem with MVC Routing how to set default action of all Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

my RouteConfig like this :

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] { "GPTKish.Controllers" }
        );
```

When I enter for ex : http://localhost:23594/News , show me Index Action of News Controller
but when i enter http://localhost:23594/NewsImages , get HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden!!!!
and don't show index action of NewsImages Controller !!!
where is wrong of my code?
this is my newsImages controller

```
public class NewsImagesController : Controller
{
    private DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext();

    // GET: NewsImages
    public ActionResult Index(int selectedNewsid)
    {

        List<NewsImage> newsImages = db.NewsImages.Include(n => n.News).Where(c => c.NewsId == selectedNewsid).ToList();
        ViewBag.NewsTitle = newsImages[1].News.Title;
        return View(newsImages);
    }
```

thank you

Comment: can u post your `NewsImages` controller code in the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This URL -  http://localhost:23594/NewsImages - doesn't provide a value for `selectedNewsId`. If you want to show images for NewsId = 5, the URL should be http://localhost:23594/NewsImages?selectedNewsId=5

Answer (score 3):

It's because Index is expecting a parameter: selectedNewsid.

http://localhost:23594/NewsImages?selectedNewsid=0 or (if using the HttpGet Attribute) http://localhost:23594/NewsImages/0 should resolve.

Two options:

1) Make selectedNewsid be optional and (optional) add a HttpGet Attribute (due to the parameter)

```
[HttpGet("{selectedNewsid")]
public ActionResult Index(int selectedNewsid = 0)
{
    if(selectedNewsid == 0)
    {
       //Show all news images
    }else{
        List<NewsImage> newsImages = db.NewsImages.Include(n => n.News).Where(c => c.NewsId == selectedNewsid).ToList();
        ViewBag.NewsTitle = newsImages[1].News.Title;
        return View(newsImages);
    }
}
```

2) Create a new default action without a parameter

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```